# if statement and Imageview

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I need to display and image according a value. but with my code only  display the last line.

The value is 2 to put an example, so the image to be displayed must be "srm2", but my code display the image corresponding with the value 6.

why???

```
 totsrmI=((int) Math.round(totsrmI));
    if (totsrmI==2) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm2);
    }
    if (totsrmI==3) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm3);
    }
    if (totsrmI==4) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm4);
    }
    if (totsrmI==5) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm4);
    }
    if (totsrmI==6) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm6);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have if else statements in more amount then it is more convenient to use switch case as switch is faster than if-else.

```
switch(totsrmI)
{
case 2:
colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm2);
break;

case 3:
colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm3);
break;
case 4:
colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm4);
break;

case 5:
colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm5);
break;

case 6:
colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm6);
break;

default:
break;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (totsrmI==2) {
    colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm2);
} else if (totsrmI==3) {
    colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm3);
} else if (totsrmI==4) {
    colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm4);
} else if (totsrmI==5) {
    colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm4);
} else if (totsrmI==6) {
    colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm6);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is useful. I prefer people answering, not voting negative a question!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was not the code, it was where the code was writed.
My variable is on a method, and I wrote the if statement outside this method

I corrected and now is inside the method

```
   totsrmI=((int) Math.round(totsrmI));
    if (totsrmI==2) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm2);
    }
    else if (totsrmI==3) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm3);
    }
    else if (totsrmI==4) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm4);
    }
    else if (totsrmI==5) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm4);
    }
    else if (totsrmI==6) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm6);
    }
    else if (totsrmI==7) {
        colorpint.setImageResource(R.drawable.srm6);
    }
```